# Can I Sass --watch two different project directories at the same time?

Tags: css, sass

I have two different websites that I am working on. I am constantly switching back and forth between the two sites. Right now, I am watching one directory and when I want to compile the other site, I cancel the watch on the first directory and watch the second. I'd like to watch both at the same time. So right now I'm doing

```
sass --watch --sourcemap J:\Steph\baseconfig -l
```

Then when I want to switch to my other folder I do ctrl + c, and use

```
sass --watch --sourcemap J:\Steph\1231_v1 -l
```

Can I watch both of these at the same time? I'm just worried it will try to compile the two together as if they were the same project. This is the method I thought I'd try, but I wanted to ask before I break anything...

```
sass --watch --sourcemap J:\Steph\baseconfig J:\Steph\1231_v1 -l
```

Also, I'm using --sourcemap to get the Sass line numbers in the Chrome inspector. When I do this, it gives me a Deprecation Warning. However, if I don't do this it doesn't always make a sourcemap. Then sometimes when I do have the sourcemap, the Inspector will give me the Sass line numbers for a few second, and then switches back to giving me the CSS line numbers. How can I get this to work consistantly?

Comment: you can have more than one terminal open at a time. Just open a second console and watch the folder.

Comment: wow. didn't even realize i could have multiple consoles. Haven't worked with them much. Thanks!

Comment: Errors with source maps have nothing to do with watching multiple directories.  If you have multiple questions, ask another question (but make sure you search first!).  Don't merge the questions into one.

Comment: If your lazy like me then go to the root level where the projects reside.   And do the following   sass --watch input_sass_path:Output_sass_path  input_sass_path:Output_sass_path